# Deploy as ZIP package from Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, deployment, visual-studio-2022

In Visual Studio when you create a new Publishing Profile you can choose to Deploy the project as a ZIP package.

What does this do?

Why choose this over not deploying as a ZIPPED package?